# Mapping drive connection problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding, mac-os-x

I'm trying to connect to a team site from a mac as I am a site collection owner.

I used finder to connect to the server but I couldn't connect. Also on a Microsoft document I was told that I don't have sufficient permissions. I tried on windows machine with same credentials and it worked.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what error you are getting? could you please share the screen shot and also how you enter credential(email /live id or ..) meanwhile check this link http://kb.netvigour.com/KB/article.aspx?id=10243

Comment: Its the same creditials that works on windows

Comment: Https://site.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage and username name@site.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: Try `file://site.sharepoint.com@ssl@443/_catalogs/masterpage`.  I might have switched the ssl/443, so if it doesn't work try them reversed.

Comment: faild: URLs with the type “file:” are not supported.

Comment: try with this url "https://site.sharepoint.com"... remove the _catalogs/masterpage from the url

Comment: what is your MAC os is?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a simple issue a while back. Please try the following, from John Ross's blog.

Here’s how you connect your Mac with OSX to a SharePoint library — this requires Office for Mac 2011:

1. From Spotlight look for “Microsoft Document Connection” and open it.
2. Click on the “Add Location” button in the upper left and choose to “Connect to a SharePoint Site…”
3. Press the Connect button.

Original post: http://johnrossjr.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/connecting-a-mac-with-osx-to-sharepoint-including-o365/